# Drupal site is compromised by backdoor

Tags: views, 7, theming, updating, cron

My Drupal site has been compromised.

Although I applied all modules updates and update my Drupal core to 7.35, it is still compromised.

What would the next logical step to take be?

Comment: Backup site for analysis; delete the entire site; restore from latest known good backup; patch and update to current standards; change ALL credentials.

Comment: i already did. only didnt changed theme folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to hear that. The steps you should take are as follows:

- If you have drush access, install [drupalgeddon](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgeddon) by typing `drush dl drupalgeddon`.
- Run `drush drupalgeddon-test`. You will likely find several accounts which you did not create. Remove them.
- Install [hacked](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) to find out which (if any) files have been changed.
- Read [this article](https://www.drupal.org/node/2365547).